# php обрезать https http www

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как с помощью php, из строки `https://site.com` сделать `site.com` из `http://site.com` сделать `site.com` и к тому же из `http(s)://www.site.com` сделать site.com`?

то есть нужно обработать ссылки обрезав префиксы `https`, `http`, `www`

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант:

```
<?php
$urls = [
    'http://site.com',
    'http://www.site.com',
    'https://site.com',
    'https://www.site.com',
    'www.site.com',
    '//site.com',
    '//www.site.com',
];
$output = preg_replace('/^(https?:)?(\/\/)?(www\.)?/', '', $urls);
print_r($output);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => site.com
    [1] => site.com
    [2] => site.com
    [3] => site.com
    [4] => site.com
    [5] => site.com
    [6] => site.com
)
```

Answer (score 3):

С помощью фнкции [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php) можно много чего интересного делать:

```
$url = 'https://site.com';

var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST));
```

Выведет:

```
string(8) "site.com"
```

Если хотите и `www` убирать, то самый простой вариант нашел такой:

```
$url = 'https://www.site.com';

$result = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);

if (strpos($result, 'www.') == 0) {
    $result = str_replace('www.', '', $result);
}

var_dump($result);
```

Вывод будет тот же.

Можно конечно без проверки сразу делать `str_replace`, но это уже ваш выбор.